# How to summarize a portion of a group of lists into a table

Tags: r, list, kableextra

I am trying to pull the results of several queries into a single table. All of the results are in a list of lists, often as single numbers from a statistical evaluation. I also need to be able to specify which of the lists results I want to tabulate. For an example set of lists:

```
list1 <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)
  names(list1) <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")
list2 <- list(10, 11, 12, 13)
  names(list2) <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")
list3 <- list(100, 101, 102, 103)
  names(list3) <- c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")
```

I can grab the results individually from each list:

```
library(magrittr)

row1 <- list1[c("second", "third")] %>%
  rbind() %>%
  unlist()

row2 <- list2[c("second", "third")] %>%
  rbind() %>%
  unlist()

row3 <- list3[c("second", "third")] %>%
  rbind() %>%
  unlist()
```

then add them to a data frame, then name each column, and final print the result

```
library(kableExtra)
desired_table <- rbind(row1, row2, row3)
colnames(desired_table) <- c("second", "third")

kbl(desired_table)
```

It seems to me like there should be an easier way, and I expect there is.

How can I do this with a list of package results, either with another package or in a way that I have not thought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like "$", the square-bracket is a an infix operator that is a disguised function call. You could even write `"["(list(0,1,2,3), 1)`, and expect to get 0.

The `sapply` function is creating successive calls, the first of which is `list(list1,list2,list3)[[1]][ c("second", "third") ]`, the second `list(list1,list2,list3)[[2]][ c("second", "third") ]`, etc. Underneath the hood, `sapply` and `lappy` are just disguised for-loops with an implicit sequential integer iterator.

Here's a base application of a composition of a couple of standard R functions (`"["` aned `sapply`)  that does it as a one liner:

```
t( sapply( list(list1,list2,list3), "[", c("second", "third") ) )
     second third
[1,] 2      3    
[2,] 11     12   
[3,] 101    102
```

```
library(kableExtra)
desired_table <- t( sapply(list(list1,list2,list3), "[", c("second", "third") ) )
png()
kbl(desired_table); dev.off()
```

Might want to add a bit of space between those two columns:

[image]

Comment: Thank you IRTFM, this is quite helpful. Question: what is the `"["` character doing in the `sapply` call? I can't really make it out from the documentation.

Comment: Added explanation to the preamble. I applaud the study of the help page. Studying the documentation of `?"["` will pay dividends in your progress towards R mastery.

Comment: Perfect - I had never seen the `[` used as a single operator, only in pairs - I didn't realize it could be used that way. This make much more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `modify_depth` from `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)

my_nested_list <- list(list1, list2, list3)

second <- modify_depth(my_nested_list, 1, "second") %>% 
  unlist()
third <- modify_depth(my_nested_list, 1, "third") %>% 
  unlist()

desired_table <- cbind(second, third)
colnames(desired_table) <- c("second", "third")

desired_table
```

```
     second third
[1,]      2     3
[2,]     11    12
[3,]    101   102
```

Comment: Thank you - the `modify-depth` call seems like it would be useful within a function that pulls out the desired results and puts them into a table. I had not seen that particular one before.